# PHP - problema com Unlink

Tags: php

Caros amigos.

Estou com o seguinte problema que não estou conseguindo resolver. 
Criei uma rotina para Alterar Imagens usando a Função UNLINK, mas não estou conseguindo.

Altera apenas os Dados menos as imagens, mesmo colocando o caminho da pasta correta, abaixo postei o meu código fonte:

```
// Carrega as funções e exteções
include("../funcao/funcao_atualizar.php");
include("../funcao/funcao_select2.php");
include("../../extensoes/url_amigavel.php");

// Resgata os valores do formulário
$titulo = utf8_decode($_REQUEST['titulo']);
$url=  url_amigavel($titulo);
$resumo= utf8_decode($_REQUEST['resumo']);
$conteudo= utf8_decode($_REQUEST['conteudo']);
$data= $_REQUEST['data'];
$id= $_REQUEST['id'];

// Verifica se o campo Imagem foi selecionado
if($_FILES['img']['name'] == false){

    //Caso negativo, atualiza os dados sem atualizar o campo img_destaque
    atualizar(array("titulo","url","resumo","conteudo","data"),
              array($titulo,$url,$resumo,$conteudo,$data),"portifolio","Where id = $id");

    // Retorna a página Portifólio com a informação de atualização
    header("location: ../portifolio.php?info=ok");

} else {
    // Se o campo img retornar valor ele faz o upload da imagem.

    // Cria uma matriz com as definições da pasta, tamanho, extensões que a imagem deve conter. 
    // Também habilita e desabilita a renomiação do arquivo da imagem
    $_UP['pasta'] = '../../img/portifolio/';

    $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb

    $_UP['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');

    $_UP['renomeia'] = true;

    // Verifica se as extenção do arquivo é permitida
    $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['img']['name'])));
    if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
        header("location: ../editar_portifolio.php?info=erro-extesao");
        exit;
    }

    // Verifica se o tamanho é inferior ao relacionado na Matriz $_UP
    else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['img']['size']) {
    header("location:../editar_portifolio.php?info=erro-tamanho");
    exit;
    }

    // Caso imagem esteja com tamanho adequado e extensão permitida, realiza a troca do nome E O UPLOAD
    else {

        if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {

        $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
        } else {

        $nome_final = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {

        } else {

        header("location: ../editar_portifolio.php?info=erro-img");
        exit;
        }

    }

    //Depois do upload ele faz uma consulta para selecionar o campo img_detaque para excluir a imagem antiga
    $consulta= select("portifolio","img_destaque","Where id = $id");

    // Verifica se consegue encontrar o campo
     if($consulta == true){
            // Caso positivo monta a matriz e resgata o resultado
            for($i=0; $i<count($consulta); $i++){
                $excluir_img = $consulta[$i]['img_destaque'];
            }

            // Exclui a Imagem ANTIGA do diretório - aqui está o erro
            // não acha a pasta e não altera no Banco.
            unlink("../../img/portifolio/$excluir_img");
    }

    //Faz a atualização dos campos e da incluse do nome da imagem no banco de dados
    atualizar(array("titulo","url","resumo","conteudo","data","img_destaque"),
          array($titulo,$url,$resumo,$conteudo,$data,$nome_final),"portifolio","Where id = $id");

    // Retorna a página Portifólio com a informação de atualização
    header("location:../portifolio.php?info=ok");
}
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Se as imagens tem o mesmo nome que as antigas, pode ser o cache da navegador que está mostrando a imagem antiga, por isto "parece" que as fotos não alteram.

Comment: Caro amigo, não aparece nenhum erro, simplesmente não altera a Imagem na Pasta de destino e nem salva no Banco de Dados. Como consigo resolver este problema? Onde devo efetuar a alteração? Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, a menos que se faça o upload de uma imagem com o mesmo nome da que já existe no servidor, as imagens nunca serão "trocadas", já que o nome será diferente, coexistirão na pasta.

Dito isto,
1º verifique se você tem permissão de escrita nesta pasta 'portifolio', se não tiver permissão de escrita (777) não será possível nem salvar a nova imagem nem apagar a antiga.
2º inverta a ordem das coisas. Primeiro apague a imagem antiga (`unlink`) ou renomeie-a, e só depois salve a nova imagem (`move_uploaded_file`).
3º por fim, verifique se o novo arquivo realmente não possui o mesmo nome do anterior antes de atualizar o nome no banco, se for o mesmo você pula esta etapa, já que nada mudará.

## Exemplo

```
<?php
$directorio = "../imagens/";
$produto = array("titulo"=>"ABC", "preco"=>100, "descricao"=>"A...Z", "imagem"=>"ABC.jpg");
$produto_nome = $directorio . basename($produto["imagem"]);
        if(file_exists($produto_nome)){
            chmod("$produto_nome", 0755);    
        }
// Outras ações
?>
```

Sendo que depois deste pequeno processo, estarás apto para decidir se removes a imagem existente, se renomeias ou algo do gênero.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o arquivo foi excluído e o sistema está tentando re-excluir um arquivo que não existe mais, gerando um erro, experimente fazer isso:

```
if (file_exists("../../img/portifolio/{$excluir_img}")) {
    unlink("../../img/portifolio/{$excluir_img}");
}
```